# How to install sbt in its latest version in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, java, jar

I am facing this [Spark problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318343/create-jar-for-spark), after installing sbt like this[.](https://gist.github.com/bigsnarfdude/b2eb1cabfdaf7e62a8fc) How to proceed please?

When hitting *tab* to this: `sudo apt-get install s` I do not see any `sbt` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do this

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 642AC823
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

to install sbt